# Png image crop, and plot

Tags: r

Is there a simple way to crop a specified pixel location of a png image, and raster that image onto a plot.

Currently i am working with dissociated cells (up to 1000 cells in a field of view).  Each cell has a center x (in pixels) and a center y (in pixels).  We gather data in trace format, so i would like a way of displaying the picture of the cells next to the trace.

I have tried rasterImage, and grid.raster.  Unfortunately i have no idea how to call upon the image array to specify the location.

Also, i do not want to use the zoom package since the functions work extremely slow and are not able to raster onto a current plot.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the raster package. The raster::raster function, for importing or coercing your png and raster::crop for subsetting to a specific extent.

Here is an example from the crop functions help.

Create an example raster

```
r <- raster(nrow=45, ncol=90)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
```

Subset the raster based on a define extent

```
e <- extent(-160, 10, 30, 60)
rc <- crop(r, e)
```

Plot results

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
  plot(r)
  plot(rc)
```

Answer (score 1):

It was alot easier than expected.  My PNG image was an array with 3 layers.

```
img[xpos, ypos, layer]
```

Therefore i could simply specify the location of my cells increased by a factor,

```
rasterImage(img[(x-x*.2):(x+x*.2), (y-y*.2):(y+y*.2),],-2, 4, 3, 1)
```

Now i need to code around for cells at the limits of my plots.